# Why openssl shows www.google.com sha1WithRSAEncryption?

Tags: tls

According to [Chromium Blog](http://blog.chromium.org/2014/09/gradually-sunsetting-sha-1.html), Google Chrome 39 with SHA-1 certificate will show a yellow icon, but my Google Chrome shows:

[Google Chrome (39.0.2171.99 (64-bit) on Ubuntu 12.04)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0szgJ.png)

I've confirmed it's SHA-1 by OpenSSL:

```
$ openssl s_client -showcerts -connect www.google.com:443 2>&1 < /dev/null | \
  openssl x509 -text | \
  grep 'Signature Algorithm' 
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've missed important information from the blog entry you link to (I've marked the relevant part):

> Sites with end-entity (“leaf”) certificates **that expire on or after 1 January 2017**, and which include a SHA-1-based signature as part of the certificate chain, will be treated as “secure, but with minor errors”.

The certificate for Google expires 15/10/3 so it is not affected by this condition.